# PHP fastest way to apply strong blur

Tags: php, image, gaussian

I need to write a script to blur an image. That wouldn't be a problem if I didn't need it to blur it **really hard**.

Now, GD's gaussian blur filter is really weak. And [imageconvolution](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php) accepts only 3x3 matrixes for some reason so I can't generate [gaussian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur#Sample_Gaussian_matrix) with larger radius for stronger blur? Even if I could, I'm not sure how fast it would be.

Running gaussian blur multiple times does the trick, but is **really** slow. To achieve effect I'm searching for, I need to run it 40-100 times over an image, and, ofcourse, it takes 10-20 seconds to finish.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for in reasonable time using libraries that come bundled with PHP?

Here is the exact effect. **Generation time: 10.972307920456 seconds. 80 passes.**

## Original:

[image]

## Processed:

[image]

Comment: You could check how ImageMagick would perform. It has PHP native interface: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/

Comment: But I need it to come bundled with PHP, and it doesn't unfortunately. I would be really happy if somebody even knew about some extremely inaccurate but really fast algorithm which I could run over the image on per-pixel basis.

Comment: But GD (what you are currently using) is NOT bundled with PHP. It just has wrapper for PHP much like IM...

Comment: You could check out [stackblur](http://badassjs.com/post/1298940200/stackblur) filter and port it to PHP.

Comment: A differt approach you could try is to resize the image to 10% of its original size and then either blow it up again or just have the browser render it in it's original size.

Answer (score 0):

`bool Imagick::blurImage ( float $radius , float $sigma [, int $channel ] )`

a). `$radius`
Blur radius

b). `$sigma`
Standard deviation

c). `$channel`
The Channeltype constant. When not supplied, all channels are blurred.